# Cannot uninstall Kinguser

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

So when I installed Kinguser,it was a old version like 2 years ago ver,and there is no root uninstall/uninstaller.
It also doesn't allow me to connect to my wifi for some reason,and I can't remove it using android,can only disable it.
How can I get rid of it??Is there any way?

Comment: It would be useful to have a bit more information. What is the model of the phone (Samsung, LG?) What version of Kinguser do you have?

Comment: I believe you can flash kinguser into the recovery again and it should override the old version. Make sure to backup your files first to make sure nothing gets lost in the process.